# Parse line of JSON using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this method:

```
lines = rec.split("\n")
rec = ''
size = len(lines)
i=0
for line in lines:
    try:
        self.on_data(json.load(line))
    except:
        logging.warning ('warning, could not parse line:', line)
        if i == size - 1:
            # if it is the last element, we can keep it, since it might not be complete
            rec+=line
    finally:
        i += 1
```

I am getting this error:

```
Message: 'warning, could not parse line:'
Arguments: ('{"readersCount":0,"uuid":"17f5fe87-5140-4f34-ac32-d325beb6b2a1","key":"bar","lockRequestCount":0,"type":"lock","acquired":true}',)
```

it looks like I need to read this first element of a tuple or something? the JSON looks ok?

Comment: `json.loads(line)` is what you're looking for

Comment: `self.on_data(json.loads(line))`

Comment: oh wowza, would not have caught that, thanks, I guess I can look up the difference, but what is it?

Comment: `loads` reads a string `load` takes a file like object

Comment: @melon `{"key": 1}` is valid json

Comment: Hmmm using loads instead of load I am getting `Message: 'warning, could not parse line:'
Arguments: ('',)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments already, you need `self.on_data(json.loads(line))`:

```
lines = rec.split("\n")
rec = ''
size = len(lines)
i=0
for line in lines:
    try:
        self.on_data(json.loads(line))
    except:
        logging.warning ('warning, could not parse line:', line)
        if i == size - 1:
            # if it is the last element, we can keep it, since it might not be complete
            rec+=line
    finally:
        i += 1
```

Comment: I am getting `Message: 'warning, could not parse line:'
Arguments: ('',)`

Comment: @rakim perhaps a check for empty line? I would go the  something like `content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]` in the beginning of reading